# Change Activity theme programmatically dosen't work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, runtimeexception

I want change app theme from code but it doesn't work .

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(R.style.NightMode);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Errors

> > E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >         Process: com.w7orld.animex, PID: 23421
> >         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.w7orld.animex/com.w7orld.animex.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> >          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
> >             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:345)
> >             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
> >             at com.w7orld.animex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
> >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Why would want to change the theme programmatically, in onCreate? You should set it in the activity declaration instead.

Comment: I want support night mode so i should be changed it in onCreate.

Comment: How can i do it ??. Must be make the main activity without actionbar because have custom toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way to do that. In onCreate i put this

```
setTheme(Designs.getThemeNoActionBar(this));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

get the theme from shared preferences and return theme without actionbar.

```
  public static int getThemeNoActionBar(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Designs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int theme = sharedPreferences.getInt("theme", R.style.AppTheme);
        if (theme == nightModeTheme)
            return R.style.NightMode_NoActionBar;
        else if (theme == theme1)
            return R.style.Theme1_NoActionBar;
        else 
             return R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar;
    }
```

In style res

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="NightMode.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme1.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's basically what the tutorial showed, that i posted. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

We set the Night-mode like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
 public static final String TAG = "App";

private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

 @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();

  // We load the Night Mode state here
   SharedPreferences mPrefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   this.isNightModeEnabled = mPrefs.getBoolean(“NIGHT_MODE”, false);
 }

public boolean isNightModeEnabled() {
   return isNightModeEnabled;
 }

public void setIsNightModeEnabled(boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
   this.isNightModeEnabled = isNightModeEnabled;
  }
}
```

As this instance will be launched before everything else, you will be able to call isNightModeEnabled() whenever you want and as such, in any Activity once your app is opened.

```
public final class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private final static String TAG = “FeedActivity”;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (MyApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled()) {
       setTheme(R.style.FeedActivityThemeDark);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
 }
}
```

> How to work with night-mode in Android is [posted here](https://carthrottle.io/how-to-implement-flexible-night-mode-in-your-android-app-f00f0f83b70e)

Here is some example pictures showing the difference between cycling though light and night mode:

[image: Light and dark mode]

Answer (score -1):

The first problem that's visible is the placement of these lines:

```
setTheme(R.style.NightMode);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You must always place the `setContentView(layout)` call immediately after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. Because this is the code that's generating the layout and its views.

Comment: "You must always place the setContentView(layout) call immediately after the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" - no, you don't. If I want to add several fields that aren't related to the layout between onCreate and setContentView, that won't magically make the app crash.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can have a `setContentView`less activity without any problem. Pointless, yes, but still allowed and possible